# How to specify default value for Boolean field with @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedDefault annotation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How to specify default value for Boolean field with DynamoDBAutoGeneratedDefault

```
@DynamoDBTyped(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.DynamoDBAttributeType.BOOL)
@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedDefault(Boolean.TRUE) private Boolean shouldProcess;
```

Boolean.TRUE seems to throw error `Attribute value must be constant`.
Is "true" right way?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently interface only accepts [string](https://appdoc.app/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-osgi/1.11.32/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBAutoGeneratedDefault.html), simply changing it to `true` throws this error.

```
Incompatible types. Found: 'boolean', required: 'java.lang.String'
```